# Insert values dynamically in database using CI active record?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I have function which fetches data from external database and I get specific film information such as id, name, genre etc. Now if movie genre is for example Animation I want only this one genre to be added to db. Now I can solve issue using isset but then I will have db entries for genres null and I want to avoid this. What is best way to approach this problem? Using foreach loop?

```
$records = array(
    array('film_id' => $movies['id'], 'genre_id' => $movies['genre'][0]),
    array('film_id' => $movies['id'], 'genre_id' => $movies['genre'][1]),
    array('film_id' => $movies['id'], 'genre_id' => $movies['genre'][2])
);

$this->db->insert_batch('film_genre', $records);
```

Comment: How do you query the external database? Could you select the records where the genre matches the specified genre (e.g. Animation), rather than returning records that match all genres? If not, then you're suggestion of iterating through the records could work.

Comment: I get specific query back based on movie title so I can't select anything else.

Comment: As you have already suggested, use a foreach loop. You can filter the results (remove a record from the $records array), or instead insert_batch, use a regular insert, one record at a time (depending on your condition).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$arr = array(

    array("id"=>3, "genre"=>"action"),
    array("id"=>13, "genre"=>"comedy"),
    array("id"=>23, "genre"=>"action"),
    array("id"=>53, "genre"=>"comedy"),
    array("id"=>63, "genre"=>"drama"),
    array("id"=>73, "genre"=>"action"),
    array("id"=>83, "genre"=>"drama"),

);

function genre($var)
{
    if($var['genre'] == 'action')
    {
        return $var;
       // you can also do the insert here like $this->db->insert();
    }
}

$filtered = array_filter($arr, "genre");

print_r($filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group your fetched data using Mysql's `GROUP BY` function